# I want to know more about German language leaning for admission to German universities

Tags: german, certifications

I am going to earn my degree in 1 to 2 years. For my higher education, for getting admission to German universities, it is compulsory to learn German or you must have a certificate of German language learning.

Is there any official online community which gives me a government approved certificate? Can you please tell me where should I have to enroll to get a certificate for that language or at what  level (B1, B2, B3) of German language should I learn for getting admission for higher education?

What should I have to do next? Please guide me.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

German universities typically make admission requirements available on their websites. They also describe what level of German is required in foreign applicants. Below are three examples:

- [Deutschkenntnisse für das Studium und die Bewerbung an der Freien Universität Berlin](https://www.fu-berlin.de/studium/international/studium_fu/deutschkenntnisse/index.html),
- [Deutschkenntnisse (Universität Bonn)](https://www.uni-bonn.de/de/studium/bewerbung-zulassung-und-einschreibung/deutschkenntnisse),
- [Ausländische Bewerber / Bewerbung mit ausländischem Schulabschluss (Stuttgart Media University](https://www.hdm-stuttgart.de/studieninteressierte/bewerber/auslaendische_bewerber/#deutschkenntnisse).

Unless you want to study German linguistics or literature, the required level of German is DSH-2 or another certificate that for an equivalent level. DSH stands for [Deutsche Sprachprüfung für den Hochschulzugang or "German language examination for university entrance"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Sprachpr%C3%BCfung_f%C3%BCr_den_Hochschulzugang).

One of the most common alternatives (and for which I have helped Chinese students prepare) is TestDaF level 4 (TDN 4). [TestDaF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestDaF) stands for Test Deutsch als Fremdsprache ("Test of German as a foreign language"). In order to reach level 4 in TestDaF, you need to reach at least level 4 in each part of the exam (reading skills, listening skills, writing skills, speaking skills).

Other alternative certificates include [telc C1](https://www.telc.net/en/candidates/language-examinations/tests/detail/telc-deutsch-c1.html) and the [Goethe-Zertfikat C1](https://www.goethe.de/de/spr/kup/prf/prf/gc1.html). These certificates correspond roughly to level C1 in the [Common European Framework of Reference for Languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages). You need to check the information on the website of the university where you want to apply to make sure that you are preparing for a certificate that they accept.

If you want to study German linguistics or literature, the required level is higher, namely TestDaF level 5, DSH-3, [Goethe-Zertifikat C2:
Grosses Deutsches Sprachdiplom](https://www.goethe.de/de/spr/kup/prf/prf/gc2.html) or a similar certificate for the same level. C2 of the CEFR represents a near-native level of German.

This means that in addition to reaching the required level of German, you also need a bit of preparation for the exam format itself. However, courses that prepare you specifically for one of these exams (15-20 hours of instruction to prepare for TestDaF) typically assume that you already have the required level as a result of other language courses. So your first task is to take your level of German to level C1 in the CEFR framework.